# Separate branches for development and production with slight changes in code base

Tags: git

I have a configuration file for my project, a single line in that file tells the program which database to use. There's a development and production database.

Is there a way in the git flow to ignore changes to this file so that the development and production branch contain different versions of this file?

Comment: This is actually a Frequently Asked Question, though somewhat in disguise: see https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I didn't think this was something which was addressed by git. Although I still wish there was a better way to handle this.

Comment: Generally the whole idea of a "branch specific file" in Git is wrong, because *branches* (branch names, really) don't have much of an existence in Git. *Commits* are what you have (forever) in Git. As you deploy something, you'd generate the appropriate runtime config based on what you're deploying, perhaps using committed pieces that get assembled or tweaked during the deployment. This is why Git needs a good deployment system (outside of Git proper).

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I'm asking the wrong question, I should probably find a way to handle this in my deployment setup